# Loaded swf does not display

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to use the Loader class to load an swf animation. If I do addChild(ldr); the animation is displayed and perma-looped, but if I try it as below, the animation doesn't display.

```
    public var ldr:Loader;
    public var explosion:MovieClip;
    public var req:URLRequest;

    ldr = new Loader();
    req = new URLRequest("../graphics/explosion1.swf");
    ldr.load(req);
    ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
```

and

```
public function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event):void {
```

explosion = ldr.content as MovieClip;
   addChild(explosion);
  }

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure, but it may be a simple security problem : loaderInfo.content is subject to security restrictions : http://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#content

so then your ldr.content as MovieClip fails silently, and explosion is null :)

addChild(ldr) should be just fine for what you're doing, but if you really need access to contentLoaderInfo.content, you should either use Security.allowDomain(domain of your main app) in your explosion1.swf or set a crossdomain policy in the repertory.

hope this helps.